# Is this the right way to declare pointers

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Point point1 = new Point(x:1, y:1);
        Point point2 = point1;
        point1.x = 3;
        point1.y = 4;
        System.out.println(point2);
    }
}
```

[image: error]

Comment: probably you copied code from a screenshot or video - `x:` and `y:` are **not part** of the code, they are inserted by some IDE to show the arguments name, they must not be typed in

Comment: Your question is not about pointers, but points, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `x and y` from `new Point(x:1, y:1)`.

Try the below code snippet.

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Point point1 = new Point(1, 1);
        Point point2 = point1;
        point1.x = 3;
        point1.y = 4;
        System.out.println(point2);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
java.awt.Point[x=3,y=4]
```